# :!python does not run my Python coding in vim

Tags: python-3.x

Running Python 3.4 and VIM 7.3 on a Windows 7 machine. Installed all programs as directed. After writing a simple program in Vim (basically

N=Myname

print n

I tried running it with command

:!python

Nothing but errors about not being an command and Shell error 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**`:!python` isn't any kind of windows command.**  See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html) for basics of how to run a python program in windows.  You run it via:  `python your_program_name.py`.  It sounds like you're trying to use a `vim` command from the windows shell (which won't work).  Even running your program inside of vim would take a similar command, like perhaps:  `:!python your_program_name.py` (or even `:!python %`, since vim will then substitute the name of your current file in for the `%`'